# Increase number of category Wordpress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, limit

Is possible change number on post/product category display in wordpress admin area?

Now is 20, but i need 50 per page.

```
<?php
function change_admin_pagination(){
global $per_page, $wp_query;
$per_page = 500;
$posts_per_page = 25;
$wp_query->query('showposts='. $posts_per_page);
}
add_action('admin_head', 'change_admin_pagination');
?>
```

I found this but is for post per page in admin area.

Comment: I think there is no way to do it, use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-posts-per-page/ and it's better to use plugin instead modifying the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is default option in wordpress, Click on screen option and select Number of items per page.

Click [Here](https://drive.google.com/a/rvtechnologies.com/file/d/1my10IQ_gXuDdCnchw0U_oE4GZvPFN28J/view?usp=drivesdk) to view screen shot

Answer (score 1):

1. Head to either the Posts or Pages index page
2. At the top right of the window select the ‘Screen Options’ tab
3. Override the default value and apply the change.